# How to create a (math) function for the position of a billiard ball when considering friction

Tags: python, math, simulation, collision, math-functions

so I'm creating a billiard ball simulation. The current version I have calculates the new position of the ball for each step, but I would like to create a math function (f(x)) for the balls position. This is not too hard, but what is really tripping me out is getting it to work with friction.

For the ball I have the following relevant information: Speed/velocity, position/startpos and friction coefficient.
I am able to calculate the distance the ball moves in a single step by raising the friction coeff to the power of x. The problem is that I can only get it to work by calculating the new position step by step. I have illustrated it in Ti-Nspire:

[image: Defining function and different values]

[image: Spreadsheet of values (look at bottom of image for code in cells)]

[image: Points visualized]

If this is in the end is harder and less efficient that just updating each second, please let me know. If you have a solution to how I could get it as a function or a better solution, please let me know too. Thanks for any help in advance:)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the velocity diminish proportionally to its current magnitude in continuous time (vs. discrete time steps) is pretty much the definition of [exponential decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay). That means the continuous time function corresponding to your discrete-stepped scaling would be

> V(t) = V<sub>0</sub> e<sup>-λt</sup>

where V<sub>0</sub> is the initial velocity at time 0 and λ is the rate of decay. We need to calibrate the decay rate to correspond with your *friccoef*, which means we want

> V(1) =  *friccoef* * V<sub>0</sub>,

and thus

> e<sup>-λ*1</sup> = *friccoef*

yielding

> λ = -ln(*friccoef*).

We can then derive the distance covered as a function of time t by integrating the velocity from 0 to t. The resulting formula for the position at time t, if movement starts at time t<sub>0</sub> with velocity V<sub>t<sub>0</sub></sub> and initial location X<sub>t<sub>0</sub></sub>, is

> X<sub>t</sub> = X<sub>t<sub>0</sub></sub> + V<sub>t<sub>0</sub></sub> (1 - e<sup>-λ(t - t<sub>0</sub>)</sup>) / λ.

To show the continuous time evolution of the function I used gnuplot with t<sub>0</sub> = 0, V<sub>0</sub> = 32, X<sub>0</sub> = 123, and *friccoef* = 0.9:

[image: Plot of location over time with stated parameterization]

Bringing it back around to stackoverflow relevance, the formulae above can be implemented straightforwardly in Python:

```python
from math import log, exp

def rate(friction_coeff):
    return -log(friction_coeff)

def position(elapsed_time, x_0, v_0, friction_coeff):
    lmbda = rate(friction_coeff)
    return x_0 + v_0 * (1.0 - exp(-lmbda * elapsed_time)) / lmbda

def velocity(elapsed_time, v_0, friction_coeff):
    return v_0 * exp(-rate(friction_coeff) * elapsed_time)

def time_to(destination, x_0, v_0, friction_coeff):
    lmbda = rate(friction_coeff)
    return -log(1.0 - lmbda * (destination - x_0) / v_0) / lmbda
```

A few simple test cases...

```python
# A few test cases
x_0 = 2
destination = 12
v_0 = 5
friction_coeff = 0.9

t = time_to(destination, x_0, v_0, friction_coeff)

print(f"Time to go from {x_0} to {destination} starting at velocity {v_0} is {t}")
print(f"Position at time {t} is calculated to be {position(t, x_0, v_0, friction_coeff)}")
print(f"Velocity at time {t} is {velocity(t, v_0, friction_coeff)}")
```

produce the following output:

```text
Time to go from 2 to 12 starting at velocity 5 is 2.24595947233019
Position at time 2.24595947233019 is calculated to be 12.00000
Velocity at time 2.24595947233019 is 3.946394843421737
```